# What is the object of this sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, gerunds

> Everybody likes eating.

What is `eating` in this sentence? Is it object or the part of the verb likes?

And what if I would change the sentence:

> Everybody likes eating the food.

The food is object and eating?

Comment: I agree with SovereignSun's answer below. Some people might say it's a catenative complement, but I don't analyze it that way since we do not normally 'chain' this verb. We do not normally say something like "I like eating to do something to do something...".

Comment: I've spoken English perfectly well for many decades, and have never needed to know whether ***eating*** in your first example is a "noun" or not. You might think it's a noun because we can easily replace it with another work that's more obviously a noun, such as *Everyone likes **chocolate***. But since we can also modify it with an adverb, such as *John likes eating **quickly***, it's obviously at least a *bit* "verby". Just say ***eating*** and ***eating chocolate*** are both [complements](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/complements).

Comment: To be an object, "eating" would have to be a noun. Your example is strictly speaking ambiguous, though verb preferred ("Everybody likes to eat"). Noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in "healthy eating".

Comment: And this would be ungrammatical: *Everybody likes healthy eating the food.*

Comment: @user178049 Analyzing *eating the food* as a noun phrase doesn't work because *eating the food* doesn't have the shape of a noun phrase.  *Eating* is clearly verbal within the subordinate clause *eating the food*, as it takes a direct object, takes adverbial modification rather than adjectival, cannot be determined, cannot inflect like a noun, and so on.  The constituent as a whole is *functionally similar* to a noun phrase, though, which is where the "gerunds are nouns" misanalysis comes from.

Comment: @snailplane I know it's not a noun. I just I think, in this case, it should be analyzed as non-finite clause functioning as a direct object.

Comment: @user178049 "Eating the food" can on be a clause since "eating" has a direct object, "food", and hence must be a verb. But the crucial point here is that most non-finite clauses don't behave like objects and should be considered as a distinct construction when they are complement of a certain kind of verb, i.e. a catenative verb.

Comment: @user178049 You also said in your first comment that "we do not normally 'chain' this verb". But that fails to take account of examples such as "I like going to the theatre" (gerund-participial) and "I like to stay home at weekends" (infinitival). Examples like these are very common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Eating**" is the direct object in the sentence. It is a gerund. If you change the sentence to "*Everybody likes eating the food*" then "**eating the food**" is a gerund phrase and is the direct object.

> A gerund always ends in **-ing** and is used as a noun. *Eating is fun.*
>
> The gerund can be a **subject** *(Eating is fun.)*; a **direct object** *(I like eating.)*; a **predicate nominative** *(A fun time is eating.)*; an **appositive** *(A fun time, eating, takes much time.)*; an **indirect object** *(I give eating too much time.)*; or an **object of a preposition** *(I give much time to eating.)* ([Daily Grammar](http://www.dailygrammar.com/211to215.shtml))

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66113/discussion-on-answer-by-sovereignsun-what-is-the-object-of-this-sentence).

Comment: Frankly, after all of this, Im confused even more than before. I would like to mark this answer as the best, but Im confused with that catenative thing.

Comment: @trenccan: You can safely call it an object. Look at rjpond's comment below. And here's a quote from the known figure in grammar, Michael Swan: [like is] not used without an **object**. _Practical English Usage fourth edition, entry 514.2_

Comment: @Mori and if the sentence would be with to + infinitive. Everybody likes to eat. “To eat” would be also direct object as in the gerund form?

Comment: Yes! It's a to-infinitive and works as the direct object of the verb _likes_.

Comment: No @trenccan.  "To eat" is **not** direct object, but **complement** of the verb "likes". Non-finite clauses as used here are not at all like direct objects, which is why we analyse them as catenative complement clauses.

Answer (score 0):

> Everybody likes eating.

*Eating* is the object of the verb *likes*.

> Everybody likes eating the food.

*Eating the food* is the object of the verb *likes*. *The food* is the object of the gerund *eating*. The object of a gerund is also called the gerund complement.

Comment: No, Mori, "Eating the food" is not the object of "likes". It is a non-finite clause functioning as catenative complement of "likes".

Comment: Then the Longman dictionary is wrong where it labels [_like_](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/like) as a [transitive](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/transitive) verb, and what is says about transitive verbs, right?

Comment: The point I am making is that "like" can be transitive ("I like **healthy eating**") and catenative ("I like **eating Chinese food**").

Comment: The dictionaries I checked don't say it _can_ be transitive — they say it _is_ transitive in this sense all the time.

Comment: As a matter of fact, this sort of complement is regarded by some grammarians as the object (see jlawler's http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/complmnt.html ).  BillJ takes his terminology from Huddleston & Pullum's *Cambridge Grammar* (which, to be fair, is a very interesting book).

Comment: @Mori Dictionaries avoid such linguistic jargon because it's difficult for learners to understand. So you'll not (maybe never) find catenative verbs in dictionaries. :)

Comment: Please remember everyone, that rule #1 on Stack Exchange is [**Be Nice**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).  There is a useful discussion to be had, but we can't have it here if we aren't going to be nice about it.